PostgreSQL connection with NodeJS and SSH-Tunnel: Always connection timeout
With a simple script I try to access a remote database over a ssh tunnel. I tried different configurations, but always at pool.connect()
Error establishing PostgreSQL connection: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
at /Users/user/Code/mvp/dat/tools/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async run (/Users/user/Code/myscript.js:61:22)`
Whats wrong in this script?
    const { createTunnel } = require('tunnel-ssh');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');

    const settings = {
      sshHost: 'host52689.provider.net',
      sshPort: 22,
      sshUsername: 'ssh-user',
      sshPrivateKeyPath: '/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa',
      sshKeepaliveInterval: 1000, 
      sshReadyTimeout: 10000, 
      // SSH port forwarding:
      dbRemoteHost: 'db01.provider.net',
      dbRemotePort: 5432, 
      dbLocalHost: '127.0.0.1',
      dbLocalPort: 5433, 
      // DB settings:
      dbName: 'db555', 
      dbUser: 'usr555',
      dbPassword: 'password' 
    };

    async function run() {

      // Create the SSH tunnel
      const [server, client] = await createTunnel(
        {
          autoClose: false
        },
        {
          port: settings.dbLocalPort
        },
        {
          host: settings.sshHost,
          port: settings.sshPort,
          username: settings.sshUsername,
          privateKey: fs.readFileSync(settings.sshPrivateKeyPath, 'utf8'),
          keepaliveInterval: settings.sshKeepaliveInterval,
          readyTimeout: settings.sshReadyTimeout,
        },
        {
          srcAddr: settings.dbRemoteHost,
          srcPort: settings.dbRemotePort,
          dstAddr: settings.dbLocalHost,
          dstPort: settings.dbLocalPort,
        }
      );
      console.log('Tunnel created.');

      // Establish a PostgreSQL connection
      const pool = new Pool({
        host: settings.dbLocalHost,
        port: settings.dbLocalPort,
        database: settings.dbName,
        user: settings.dbUser,
        password: settings.dbPassword,
        connectionTimeoutMillis: 5000,
      });

      try {
        const clientDb = await pool.connect();
        console.log('PostgreSQL connection established.');

        // .....

        clientDb.release();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error establishing PostgreSQL connection:', error);
      }

      // Close the PostgreSQL connection
      await pool.end();
      console.log('PostgreSQL connection closed.');

      // Close the SSH tunnel
      server.close();
      console.log('SSH tunnel closed.');

    }

    run().catch(error => {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    });```


The script seems to be missing some imports or something mechanical like that.  createTunnel is not defined.

found the problem:
dbRemoteHost: 'db01.provider.net'

has to be
dbRemoteHost: '0.0.0.0'

According to the first comment I have updated the question with the missing imports (first line missed during copy).
